# Remove observers from NotificationCenter in Swift

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am creating observers in the following way:

```
private func observeUserStatusNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(NotificationConstants.UserStatusUpdatedNotificationConstant), object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
            if let user = notification.object as? User {
                self?.updateTabBarWithUser(user: user)
            }
    }
}
```

I use `[weak self]` to avoid retain cycles. Since I am not registering the observer inside a block, I don't need to remove it, let's say, at `deinit()`. Am I right?

I have swiftlint installed and it throws the following warning:

> Discarded Notification Center Observer Violation: When registering for a notification using a block, the opaque observer that is returned should be stored so it can be removed later. (discarded_notification_center_observer)

May I ignore this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can ignore that warning. Starting with iOS 9 it's no longer necessary to remove the observer on dealloc. This doesn't mean that they're still not active, but it won't affect you. Unless you register a lot of times, that might cause some memory issues.

Comment: This isn't true if you use the closure based API. For observers added that way, you still need to remove the observer using the token returned. https://oleb.net/blog/2018/01/notificationcenter-removeobserver/

Comment: @JonShier this is something along the lines I said in the answer :) The notification might still be active, but since `self` is weakly captured it won't trigger side-effects.